# how to use &amp; in my answer

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I am trying to write `&amp;` in my answer but it is showing `&`.
How to solve this?
I want to give answer of one question and I required to write `&amp;` as it is.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Inline code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use code markdown `&amp;` or type in `&amp;amp;` in normal text, which turns into &amp;